# TYPO3 Upgrade ( 7.6 to 10): Site Configuration not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have been spending the day trying to upgrade my TYPO3 installation from version 7.6 to 10.4 and with some struggles in between everything went fine, to the point that I can login into the backend and so on and so forth.

The problem that I am facing for some hours now is that I can't get the front-end to work.

I get the following error:

> Page not found.
>   The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: **No site configuration found**

I have been scrolling for google for quite a bit now and I can't seem to find the right solution right now.

The way I went was to install T3-10 with composer and migrate the DB and run the upgrade wizard. I also checked for the "site configuration" within the backend and also the site configuration part in the filesystem and everything seems to be ok.

```
base: 'https://mydomain.local/'
baseVariants: {},
errorHandling: {},
languages: 
  - 
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: German
    hreflang: de_DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
    websiteTitle: ''
rootPageId: 1
routes: ''
websiteTitle: XYZ
```

I am sure it's just something little that I can't seem to find right now, anyone else experience with this?

Comment: Did you upgrade your installation version by version (7.6 > 8.7 > 9.5 > 10.4) and run the upgrade wizards for every version?

Comment: No I was just jumping ahead and did the installation from 7.6 to 10.4 directly, the backend as such works fine it's just the frontend that's not working

Comment: do you still have domain records? AFAIK there was a case where the old domain-records interfered with the site configuration

Comment: Is there only 1 site config with `rootPageId: 1`?

Comment: @JonasEberle Yes there is only 1 site config with a PID 1
 I am working on a localhost environmente with a vhost-adress xyz.local and when I look into the site configuration and the backend everything seems fine. Where would I find old domain records?

Comment: Domain Reords are records from the `sys_domain` database table. You can just truncate this table. In the TYPO3 backend they were *usually* inside the root page of any domain.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue because i wrote a http:// url in the site conf.
With https:// as well without a SSL-certificate everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the problem with a TYPO3 installation behind a proxy. Setting the following values in Global Configurations solved my problem.
(Can be done via backend in *Admin Tools* → *Settings* → *Configure Installation Wide Options* or alternatively directly in the `LocalConfiguration.php` file)

```php
'HTTP' => [
   'proxy' => '<yourProxyIp:yourProxyPort>',
],
'SYS' => [
    'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'last',
    'reverseProxyIP' => '<yourReverseProxyIp>',
    'reverseProxySSL' => '*'
]
```

Comment: Where can I found `yourReverseProxyIP` and `yourProxyPort`?

Comment: You have to ask your data center admin. She/he will know.

Comment: I am using `ddev` with Docker

Comment: You mean locally? In this case you should not need to care about it. In this case let those values empty.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using old conditions in your TypoScript Setup / Constants? From TYPO3 10 onwards you need to use the Symfony Expression Language. Take a look here and replace those in your code where needed.

```
[page["uid"] in 18..45]
# This condition matches if current page uid is between 18 and 45
# Not possible with old syntax
[END]

[34 in tree.rootLineIds || 36 in tree.rootLineIds]
# This condition matches, if the page viewed is or is a subpage to page 34 or page 36
# Old Syntax: [PIDinRootline = 34,36]
[END]

[loginUser('*')]
# Old syntax: [loginUser = *]
[END]

[page["field"] == "value"]
# Old syntax: [page|field = value]
[END]

[loginUser('*') == false]
# Old syntax: [loginUser = ]
[END]

[getTSFE().id >= 10]
# Old Syntax [globalVar = TSFE:id >= 10]
[END]

[applicationContext == "Production" && userId == 15]
# This condition match if application context is "Production" AND logged in user has the uid 15
# Old syntax: [applicationContext = "Production"] && [loginUser = 15]
[END]

[request.getNormalizedParams().getHttpHost() == 'typo3.org']
# This condition matches if current hostname is typo3.org
# Old Syntax: [globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST = www.typo3.org]
[END]

[like(request.getNormalizedParams().getHttpHost(), "*.devbox.local")]
# This condition matches if current hostname is any subdomain of devbox.local
# Old Syntax: [globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST = *.devbox.local]
[END]

[page["uid"] in [1,2,3,4] || 5 in tree.rootLineIds]
# This condition matches if current page uid is either 1,2,3 or 4
# or if the current page is 5 or any subpage of 5
[END]

[backend.user.isLoggedIn]
# This condition matches if a backend user is logged in
# Old syntax: [globalVar = TSFE:beUserLogin = 1]
[END]

[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_blog_tag/tag') > 0]
# This condition matches if current query parameters have tx_blog_tag[tag] set to a value greater than zero
[END]
```

Source: https://usetypo3.com/symfony-expression-language-in-typo3.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when deploying a project (10.4.14) from my local dev to stage environment.

Due to missing SSL cert, the configuration in the Apache 2.4. was pointing to missing cert-files.
After fixing this the site configuration was found.